# Passing a class Member function as an Argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have a class as follows and a main method as follows:

```
class Mesh
{
public:
    void draw()

    void draw(){}
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    Mesh mesh;
    glutDisplayFunc(mesh.draw);
}
```

So I want to pass a member function of an object as argument, but the compiler displays the following error message:

```
error: argument of type ‘void (Mesh::)()’ does not match ‘void (*)()’
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look up member function pointers.

Comment: `glutDisplayFunc` expects a pointer to a free function taking no parameters and returning nothing. You can't pass it a pointer to member function.

Comment: can you write the declaration of glutDisplayFunc() ?

Comment: @Aadietya, `glutDisplayFunc()` is an OpenGL function. You could read about it [here](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html)

Comment: may be you could `reinterpret_cast<void(*)(void)>(&Mesh::draw)`(honestly dont do it) but this is undefined behaviour as far as i know but compiler will allow it anyways because of the explicit cast.

Comment: The problem is that a member function pointer needs a pointer of your class to be called on... (unless it's a static function)

Comment: @Koushik But this can't use a `this` pointer, i.e. you can't *bind* something like `mesh` to such a pointer like you can with functors / lambdas...

Comment: @leemes i agree totally and thats why i mentioned its UB to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `draw` is a non-static member function, it needs an instance of the class to operate upon.

In pure C++, you would use a function object (a.k.a. "functor", see `std::function` or its predecessor `boost::function`).  That's sadly not an option in C or C APIs.

In this case, since there's no data that is handed to the callback, you must make some sort of static function (either class static or file static) that does the right thing when it is called.

If you only ever have one `Mesh`, then it's easy: either make everything in the class static (in which case it's basically a namespace), or have a non-member function that calls `draw` against the one instance of your `Mesh`:

```
// at some global-ish file scope...

// we define our class
class Mesh { ... };

// and here's the one global instance of it
Mesh myOneMesh;

// and here is our global / static function that "knows"
// which instance to draw
void drawMyOneMesh() { myOneMesh.draw(); }

// then, in the main flow of your program:
glutDisplayFunc( &drawMyOneMesh );
```

If you have multiple meshes, it looks like the best you can do is to key it off of the current window.  Without knowing much about your app or about the GLUT API, I would probably do something like this to enable a mesh-per-window callback:

```
#include <map>

// this could also be a class with all-static members, if one
// were so inclined.  might be worth it, if only to protect 'map'
// from external meddling.

namespace WindowToMesh
{

    typedef std::map< int, Mesh * > Map;
    Map map;

    void addMapping( int win, Mesh * mesh )
    {
        map.insert( { win, mesh } );
    }

    void removeMapping( int win )
    {
        map.erase( win );
    }

    void draw()
    {
        int win = glutGetWindow();
        Map::iterator it = map.find( win );
        if ( it != map.end() )
            it.second->draw();
    }

} // end namespace WindowToMesh
```

Now, in your main program, you can associate a new `Mesh` with the current window:

```
Mesh * m = new Mesh( ... );
WindowToMesh::addMapping( glutGetWindow(), m );
```

And you can associate the (effectively static) `WindowToMesh::draw` function as the callback:

```
glutDisplayFunc( &WindowToMesh::draw );
```

When you're ready to destroy the `Mesh`, make sure you're in the same window, and then:

```
WindowToMesh::removeMapping( glutGetWindow() );
```

Depending on other factors, it might make sense to do a bidirectional mapping (so you can find things by `Mesh *` and not just by window `int`, or to do a brute-force scan on the rare unregistration, etc.

I don't have an environment in which I can test that, but it should be close.  Good luck!

Comment: I think your function `register` has to be renamed, since it's a keyword. (I wouldn't have seen it if there was no syntax highlighting on SO ;))

Comment: @leemes -- Gah.  Thanks.  Got a brown paper bag I could borrow?

Comment: Now it's nice. I like how your solution can handle multiple windows. My solution lacks this feature...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a member function pointer needs **some information** to be called, i.e. the **instance** to be called on, which will then be accessible by the `this` pointer within the implementation of the member function, so you can access member variables. I think you want to do this, since your design looks like you want to draw stuff which is defined in `Mesh`.

There are possibilities to turn a member function pointer into a "normal" function pointer. But you have to keep in mind that this piece of information (the *instance* of `Mesh`) has to be available once this function is called. This means that a typical transformation from a member function pointer to a "normal" function pointer **adds a parameter** (the instance).

But `glutDisplayFunc()` accepts a `void(*)(void)` function pointer, i.e. an **empty** parameter list, so it won't tell the called function *anything*. You have to make sure that once the passed function is called, you can howsoever **reconstruct** the "context", i.e. the `Mesh` instance.

This can be done by pointing to a `Mesh` instance from a global point in your code. It will always be used when you call the helper function we are about to write. So when you pass a pointer to `glutDisplayFunc()` our helper function knows which `Mesh` to use, once we told it which it should use.

```
class Mesh
{
public:
    void draw() { ... }
}

Mesh *instance;

// Helper function called by glut:
void display() {
    // Now we can access a particular instance:
    instance->draw();
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    Mesh mesh;

    // First point to this instance globally:
    instance = &mesh;

    // Then, pass our helper function which now has an empty parameter list:
    glutDisplayFunc(&display);
}
```

This solution has a restriction. You can't reuse the same function pointer with different instances. So you can't turn *any* instance into a function pointer, but only one for each globally defined instance pointer. But since you just want to pass your draw function to `glutDisplayFunc`, you only need to do this *once*, so it should be fine. I just don't want to keep this "danger" from you. ;)